# вызов функции изменением атрибута класса

Tags: python

стоит задача отловить одной функцией результат работы другой функции по изменению атрибута класса. каким образом я могу это сделать, возможно использованием `__getattribute__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно сделать этот атрибут свойством

```py
class C:
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, x):
        print(f'value={x}')
        self._value = x

c = C()
c.value = 5 # value=5
```

Comment: вот спасибо!) разбираюсь!)))

Comment: не совсем понимаю, каким образом я тут фиксирую изменение атрибута класса и вызов какой функции это инициирует? не могли бы Вы откомментировать свое решение, буду очень признателен!)

Comment: @vladionair `С` - класс, `value` - его атрибут.. когда вы присваиваете что-то атрибуту (`c.value = что-то`), вызывается метод `value` (второй)  и может выполнять любые действия, вызывать любые функции. Если это не то, что вам нужно, уточните вопрос, а лучше задайте новый, так будет больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо за внимание! это не совсем то, что мне нужно, но это тоже интересно!